# Does the condition i < arrList.size() change each time you iterate over the loop?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void test(ArrayList<String> arrList){
   for(int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++){
      arrList.remove(i);
   }
}
```

since I am removing an element each time I iterate over the loop, the `arrList.size()` will also change each time it loops. Will the condition `i < arrList.size()` also change each time the loop iterates or will it stay constant and never change?

Comment: Why not try it out? --- Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I know that I am should use a while loop instead for something that changes in value, but I just want to know how it works.

Comment: Again: why not try it out?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. No, it will not.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. it would throw an exception, if OP used a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Of course, the condition `i < arrList.size()` changes, even when you’re not removing elements, simply because `i` changes. Otherwise, the loop would never end. The actual question, you probably wanted to ask, is whether `arrList.size()` changes and the answer is, yes, but so do the elements at the location `i` and following and since you’re still incrementing `i` in each iteration, you will unintentionally skip elements.

Answer (score 0):

The condition will be evaluated before each iteration of the loop, so changes in the size of the `List` will be reflected. However, if you remove elements while iterating over the `List`, it will cause later elements to shift forward and you will skip one element each time. Instead, use an `Iterator` to remove elements or loop backwards so that elements at indexes that have not been reached yet will not be shifted. Since it appears you want to remove all the elements, you can directly call [`List#clear`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--) instead of removing each element manually.

Answer (score 0):

It will be changed, because the "arrList.size()" will be evaluated on every loop, you can test it adding a print in your code